# How can I output an error when a condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, arrays, statements

I have a generateRandomArray function, and if the argument is not a array, it should stop the function execution and output the error to the console without printing the passed argument. If the argument is an array, it should continiue. However, the abouve code doesn't work.

```
<script>
function generateRandomArray(array){
if(typeof array != 'array'){
console.log("Uncaught typeError: the argument is not a array");
}
var storage = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
return array[storage];
}
var arrayer = generateRandomArray('d');
console.log(arrayer );
</script>
```

I tried return;, to stop the function execution but it is not working.

Comment: `throw new Error("Uncaught typeError: the argument is not a array");` is how you throw an error

Comment: `typeof array` will never be `"array"`. `Array.isArray(array)` is how you check for arrays.

Comment: "I tried return;, to stop the function execution but it is not working." Return does stop the function if you place it corretly, even if its not the best solution to your objective. Also you already have a return so by having a return without a value your function will return different types of values in different scenarios which is typically a bad idea

Comment: @Isac, I don't think so, if you read my code, the return statement is placed inside a if.else statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function generateRandomArray(array){
if(typeof array != 'array'){
console.log("Uncaught typeError: the argument is not a array");
}
var storage = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
return array[storage];
}
var arrayer = generateRandomArray('d');
console.log(arrayer );
</script>
```

As mentioned you are trying to check typeof array in javascript array also falls under object or in short array also is the object so the typeof array will be "object" so you can either check typeof array != "object" or you can simply use Array.isArray() function that will return boolean values true or false.
hope you got my point

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're checking array with wrong method. You need to use  Array.isArray(array) to check variable's type for array.

EDIT: Also you can check with Lodash by using _.isArray(array) method

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is `throw new Error("one error")` like said blex.
But if you stop the execution of your program while there is a user, it will not be good for you... so it is why you should use `console.error("another error")`

Answer (score 0):

typeof array is Object so you need to use this { Array.isArray(array) } and throw new Error('Error Message');